# Is a non-trivial plug-in for some application considered an app?

Tags: application-development, plugins

In the context of the Ubuntu App Showdown, if a useful plug-in for an existing application (in my case blender, but it could be anything) were to be developed, could it be considered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately we are not considering plugins to be apps: the contest requires applications that are their own process and deliver their own functionality as opposed to extending the functionality of another app.

This is not to say your contribution would not be valuable, we are just concious of giving everyone a level playing field in the contest - we would love to have you contribute the plugin to the community though, and do keep up updated on your progress. Thanks for asking!